# Override JavaScript (window) Function

Tags: javascript, overriding

I'd like to override a function which is being made by a javascript plugin. I know how to override regular window functions, but this is different. I'm not sure how to name it, but the structure of that function is like:

```
window.something.function
```

I have no idea how to override that. I have tried the following:

```
var originalFunction = window.something.function;
window.something.function = function(parameter) {
    alert('called');
    return originalFunction(parameter);
}
```

But it's not working.

Does someone know a solution?

**Edit:**
As I have been told my question is unclear, I have edited it again using the actual names of the plug-in.

The plugin is meant to be used as:

```
var myColor = new jscolor(target, options)
```

When this is being used, there is a function "inside" the object "jscolor" which is being called when setting the value of target element. I want to override that function to add an extra functionality without changing the original js file.

Code:

```
if (!window.jscolor) { window.jscolor = (function () {


var jsc = {
    .....
    jscolor : function (targetElement, options) {
        ....
        //Function I want to change:
        this.exportColor = function (flags) {
            if (!(flags & jsc.leaveValue) && this.valueElement) {
                var value = this.toString();
                if (this.uppercase) { value = value.toUpperCase(); }
                if (this.hash) { value = '#' + value; }

                if (jsc.isElementType(this.valueElement, 'input')) {
                    this.valueElement.value = value;
                } else {
                    this.valueElement.innerHTML = value;
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

My attempts so far:

```
var origJsColor = jscolor.exportColor;
jscolor.exportColor = function(flags) {
    console.log('called');
    return origJsColor(flags);
}
```

and the window attempt above.

Comment: You can try to run `window.something.function()` immediate after your function definition to see if the defined function is implemented as you want.

Comment: I updated my question.
@JimmyKo Thanks for your reply. My function is being called (which is obvious), but I'm getting the error "originalFunction" is not a function.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Apologies. I hope it is much more clear right now.

Comment: I believe this actually means it's a private class, so I won't ever be able to override jscolor.exportColor since exportColor is being called as "this.exportColor". Am I right?

Comment: @stefan1294: Much clearer now, nice one. I do suggest consolidating it into one cohesive question "Edit" and "Edit 2", that's how it's normally done here at SO. Meanwhile, I've answered it. You *can* override `exportColor`, but you have to do it on an instance-by-instance basis. Fortunately, you can override `jscolor` in order to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `jscolor` code you've shown creates an object with its own copy of `exportColor` (one is created for each object). So to replace it, you have to replace it on each instance as the instance is created.

You can do that as a one-off in much the way you showed, just working with the instance rather than the plugin function, and using `Function#call` to call it with the right `this`:

```
// Get the instance
var c = new jscolor(target, options)

// Update it
var origExportColor = c.exportColor;
c.exportColor = function(flags) {
    console.log('called');
    return origExportColor.call(c, flags); // Note the changes on this line
};
```

Or instead of

```
return origExportColor.call(c, flags);
```

you might use

```
return origExportColor.apply(c, arguments);
```

...if there's any chance of the function being called with anything other than exactly one argument. (`arguments` is a magic pseudo-array containing the arguments used to call the function.)

If you want to do that for **all** instance you might create, you can put a facade in front of `jscolor` to do that to each instance:

```
var realJscolor = jscolor;
jscolor = function() {
    // Call the real function, passing along all the arguments we
    // get automatically (`arguments` is a magic pseudo-array)
    var retVal = realJscolor.apply(this, arguments);

    // If it returned a non-`null` object, we want to use that instead
    // of `this`; if not, we keep using `this`
    if (!retVal || typeof retVal !== "object") {
        retVal = this;
    }

    // Slip in our version of exportColor
    var origExportColor = retVal.exportColor;
    retVal.exportColor = function(flags) {
        console.log('called');
        // (Maybe use `apply` here instead)
        return origExportColor.call(retVal, flags);
    };

    // Return the result, in case the real function overrode `this`
    return retVal;
};
jscolor.prototype = realJscolor.prototype;
```

Then just use `jscolor` normally:

```
var c = new jscolor(target, options);
```

The reason for the `retVal` thing is that although normally a `new` expression's result is a refernece to the new object created by `new`, a constructor function *can* return a non-`null` object reference and, if it does, the `new` expression's result is that object reference instead. That's why we check the return value of `realJscolor`.

Of course, that means that **all** uses of `jscolor` on the page that use the global will now use your updated function instead. If you don't want that, just use your own name and don't override `jscolor`:

```
var myColor = function() {
    var retVal = jscolor.apply(this, arguments);
    // ...and so on...
    return retVal;
};
myColor.prototype = jscolor.prototype;
```

Usage:

```
var c = new myColor(target, options);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this excellent explanation. I learned a lot by this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Function

```
function a() {alert(this)} // will print `window` obejct
```

is defined in the window scope. That is, it is a *method* of the window. Your `more difficult` situation comes from the fact that `this` is different from window if you define function as a method in another object.

```
var a = {method: function() {alert(this)}}
```

you call a.method() but see that the same window again. You need to [bind](https://www.google.ee/search?q=javascript%20bind) your function to the parent object to make it compete method.